# Open API with authentication JAVA SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

We have an application with react + java + spring boot. We have few open apis which can be accessed by anyone(no security/no authentication required) and few secured apis(requires authentication).

I want to expose few APIs to all but I want do authentication for those APIs.

Can someone suggest me what can be done? Should I look more into spring security or checkout spring OPEN-API or is there any other better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `spring security` in your project. It will allow you apply **Filter** to your API depending on your users **ROLE** or **AUTHORITY**.

Looking at this sample code below, you can see what it looks like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/management/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(COURSE_WRITE.getPermission())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/management/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(COURSE_WRITE.getPermission())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/management/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(COURSE_WRITE.getPermission())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/management/api/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), ADMIN_TRAINEE.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

More details [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg).